# Programmatically make wallpaper fit each screen and not scroll

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to programmatically set a wallpaper to be an exact fit of the current screen.

Android fits the image to scroll as you change windows by defalt and so you never see the whole image on any one screen.

Applications like Wallpaper Wizardrii perform the function of setting the image to a single screen for the user, but I have never seen an answer on any forum that suggests how this is done.

Can any Android guru out there help - this problem has been doing my head in for nearly a week now!

Answer (score 3):

You need to write a Live Wallpaper so you can render your image to the screen exactly how you want.  If you just set a static image, the launcher app (or anything else showing the wallpaper) will be free to adjust it and resize and scroll.  By writing a live wallpaper, you get to receive the requests from launcher about what it wants to happen to the wallpaper, and follow or ignore them as you want.

Also conceptually "make the wallpaper an exact fit for the current screen" is not even possible, because there is only one wallpaper, but two orientations (landscape and portrait) it can be shown in.  That one wallpaper just fundamentally can't exactly fit both orientations.